# Pronunciation of "applicable"

Tags: pronunciation

Do you pronounce the word like...

- Ap-PLIC-a-ble

Or:

- APP-lic-a-ble

And if so, is there a difference between the two?

Answer (score 2):

The NOAD reports /ˈæpləkəbəl/ as the pronunciation of the word in American English, and /əˈplɪkəb(ə)l/, /ˈaplɪkəb(ə)l/ as the British pronunciation.

In /əˈplɪkəb(ə)l/, the accent is on the second "syllable" (*Ap-PLIC-a-ble*); in /ˈæpləkəbəl/ and /ˈaplɪkəb(ə)l/, the accent is on the first "syllable" (*APP-lic-a-ble*).

Answer (score 1):

My Webster's gives them both as variant pronunciations, with the stressed first syllable being preferred. Both mean the same thing, and are identical apart from the pronunciation.

You say tomato, I say tomahto ...

Answer (score -7):

It is French.

The correct pronunciation is as it is written: AHplihKAHbleh

(the 'ah' as in *hot*)

However, due to anglicization, no one in USA cares about that pronunciation. So I've told you the correct pronunciation, but the **common** English pronunciation would have the emphasis on the **first** syllable. Don't put emphasis on the second syllable, ever.

Comment: The question is how to pronounce it in English, not French.